# Do all web hosts allow rss feeds?

Tags: rss, feeds

Simple question: Do all website hosts allow RSS feeds to be coded, such that if I have an application for my phone, and the application pulls information from my website, I could use any web host to accomplish this?

I was thinking of going with Hostmonster.com, in case you were wondering.

Thoughts?

Comment: How is this related to Windows Phone? Also, this might be better suited for SuperUser or WebMasters, SO is dedicated to programming questions.

Answer (score 4):

If the RSS feed is just a static file then it's a fair assumption that any web host should allow you to serve the file to whatever clients request it.

It wasn't specified in the question but in case the RSS feed is dynamically generated by the server when it's requested, the server would need to support the technology used to generate the file.

Answer (score 1):

[Hostmonster supports PHP5](http://www.hostmonster.com/cgi/info/hosting_features) so if you can write PHP code you can have a dynamic RSS feed. Most, if not all, hosts offer scripting language support so any host you choose should be able to support this.